# Remove Characters from Array - Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

Hi I am fairly new to Powershell and I'm trying to get some automation going, I have built the below array to capture all software installed in the environment, which will be converted to HTML to upload to a confluence page. The capture itself works fine but always happy to hear better ways of doing this. However, because of certain characters, the automation bit to confluence fails does and I cant for the life of me understand how to remove these characters from the output of the below. "**,**" "**()**" , "**+**" Please note I have taken bits from others code to achieve the below so far.

```
    $computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'operatingsystem -like "*server*" -and enabled -eq "true"' | Select-Object name

$array = @()

foreach($pc in $computers){

    $computername=$pc.name

    #Define the variable to hold the location of Currently Installed Programs

    $UninstallKey=”SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall” 

    #Create an instance of the Registry Object and open the HKLM base key

    $reg=[microsoft.win32.registrykey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey(‘LocalMachine’,$computername) 

    #Drill down into the Uninstall key using the OpenSubKey Method

    $regkey=$reg.OpenSubKey($UninstallKey) 

    #Retrieve an array of string that contain all the subkey names

    $subkeys=$regkey.GetSubKeyNames() 

    #Open each Subkey and use GetValue Method to return the required values for each

    foreach($key in $subkeys){

        $thisKey=$UninstallKey+”\\”+$key 

        $thisSubKey=$reg.OpenSubKey($thisKey) 

        $obj = New-Object PSObject

        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name “ComputerName” -Value $computername

        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name “DisplayName” -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue(“DisplayName”)) -remo

        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name “DisplayVersion” -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue(“DisplayVersion”))

        #$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name “InstallLocation” -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue(“InstallLocation”))

        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name “Publisher” -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue(“Publisher”))

        $array += $obj

    } 

}



$array | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName } | select ComputerName, DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher
```

Comment: Which property do you need to remove the characters from?

Comment: The Characters are contained in the DisplayName & Publisher properties